# Calibre: Adding ", " as a separator for splitting the authors string

Tags: calibre

All of my ebooks have a filename of the form

```
author1, author2, ... - [series seriesindex - ] title.*
```

and I have set up Calibre to read metadata from the filename.

Calibre, however, does not seem to split on ", ". How do I modify the regular expression under "Preferences"->"Tweaks" -> "Splitting multiple author names" (authors_split_regex) to add ", " as a possible separator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend this, to be honest. The general naming convention that Calibre expects as default uses comma to delimit author's first and last name, i.e. either `Jane Doe` or `Doe, Jane`. If you fiddle with the splitting regex and then try to import a book with this name pattern, you'll get into trouble - and I don't know if this tweak influences just newly imported books or all books within your library.

But if you want to experiment, this regular expression should work: `(?i),?\\s*(and|with|,)\\s+`. I would try this on a test library first, though, if I were you.

In general, I highly recommend using an online regex tester (with Python regex flavor) such as [this one](https://regex101.com/) for working with Calibre, it saved me a lot of headaches in the past.